# How to resolve: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to reconfigure the testing on my mvn project because we migrated to wildly 23 from 9 for the testing.

Error message that I am getting on all of my functional tests:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.642 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.<company>.crs.auth.authz.AuthorizationServiceTest
[ERROR] org.<company>.crs.auth.authz.AuthorizationServiceTest  Time elapsed: 12.642 s  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: <project>.war
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out
```

I know the spinup time on my wildfly instance can cause this, so I have increased the startupTimeout property. Here is my arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
                http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="serverConfig">standalone.xml</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
            <property name="startupTimeoutInSeconds">300</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

For my dependency management I have:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Wondering what might be going on here?